# Use FormView to Insert to database

Tags: asp.net

I am having a problem getting the FormView Control in Visual Studio 2010 inserting data into a SQL database I have managed to view the data that is currently in the database but when I click insert I get an error message I just don't understand what I am doing wrong

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick video of how to do this

http://sfvt.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/asp-net-tutorial-formview-insert-to-database/